# Websockets in NodeJS. Calling WebSocketServer from server-side WebSocket client

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a NodeJS web app running. I have a WebSocketServer running. I can communicate with my app via a WebSocket connection made from my javascript on the client machine fine. Here's the nodejs server-side code snippet of relevance:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var server = app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port: ' + server.address().port);
});

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    ws.on('message', function (message, flags) {
        if (flags.binary) {
            var value1 = message.readDoubleLE(0);
            var value2 = message.readInt16LE(8);
            var value3 = message.readInt8(10);

            //message.writeDoubleLE(8.5,0);

            ws.send(message, {
                binary: true
            });
        } else {
            if (message == "injest") {
                ws.send("requested: " + message);
            } else if (message == "something") {
                wss.clients[0].send('server side initiated call');
            } else {
                ws.send("received text: " + message);
            }
        }

    });

    // ws.send('something');    // Sent when connection opened.
});
```

So you see, all very simple.

Here 's my problem. How can I access this WebServer from the NodeJS code of the server-side app itself?

I tried the below:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:443");

ws.on('message', function (message) {
    wss.clients[0].send('server side initiated call 1 ');
});

ws.on('close', function (code) {
    wss.clients[0].send('server side initiated call 2 ');
});

ws.on('error', function (error) {
    wss.clients[0].send(error.toString());
});

ws.send("k");
```

The error function is triggered with ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443.

I specified no port when I set the server up. If I do then the calls to the server from my client html page fail.

So in brief how can I set up a WebSocket client in NodeJS to access a WebSocketServer created in that app?

Comment: Can you perhaps pick a more meaningful title to your question?  Tags already indicate that this is a node.js and webSocket question.  Your title should provide some context for what the question is about.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect on port 443?  Your server appears to be running on some different port.  You need to specify the port your server is actually running on.  And, keep in mind that when connecting to localhost, connections will not go through any of your hosting provider's infrastructure (proxies, etc...) so you have to connect to the actual port the server process is running on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said, I tried specifying a port for the websocket server but then my client side calls stopped working. How can I query the WebSocketServer object for the port it is running on? Also, instead of local host, would you expect the address to match the address I use from client side javascript i.e. something like wss://mywebpaceaddress.whatever.endpoint ? I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're running in a hosting environment and incoming connections to your domain on port 80 are mapped to some other port.  That mapping does not happen when you connect directly to localhost because you are bypassing the normal infrastructure that a connection to your domain goes through.  If you want that mapping, then connect to your domain, not to localhost.

Comment: Thanks all for your advice. Still can't get it working. I've simplified the question and reposted in the hope that somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `localhost`. Substitute the 127.0.0.1 for it.

1. Instantiate the Server

`let WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
let ws = new WebSocketServer({port: 9090});`

```
ws.on('connection', function (ws) {
    console.log(nHelp.chalk.red.bold('Server WebSocket was connected.'));

    //  Add the listener for that particular websocket connection instance.
    ws.on('message', function (data) {
       //code  goes here for what you need
 });

    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('websocket connection closed!');
    });

});
```

You can open other ports and routes (example for Express) in the same file, or other ports for WS as well btw.

The above is not code for Secure WS server for TLS. that is a bit different.